# Reading .dfb file with rust throws invalid character error

Tags: rust, dbf, dbase

I am new to rust and creating a POC to convert `dbf` file to `csv`. I am reading a `.dbf` file using rust library [dbase](https://docs.rs/dbase/0.0.2/dbase/).

The issue is, when i crate a sample `.dbf` file using [dbfview](https://dbfview.com/) the code works fine. But when i use `.dbf`  file which i will be using in real time. I am getting the following error.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: InvalidFieldType('M')', src/libcore/result.rs:999:5
```

Here is the code i am using from the given link.

```
use dbase::FieldValue;
let records = dbase::read("tests/data/line.dbf").unwrap();
for record in records {
    for (name, value) in record {
        println!("{} -> {:?}", name, value);
        match value {
            FieldValue::Character(string) => println!("Got string: {}", string),
            FieldValue::Numeric(value) => println!("Got numeric value of  {}", value),
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```

I think the `^M` shows the character appended by `windows`. 
What can i do to handle this error and read the file successfully.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't actually think it's down to a `^M` symbol but an `M` (Memo) field type itself. Is there a chance you could throw that `dbf` file somewhere, or at least just the field definition? `dbase-rs` [does not handle this type](https://github.com/tmontaigu/dbase-rs/blob/master/src/record/field.rs#L55)

Comment: @SébastienRenauld here is the db file on dropbox. Can you please have a look. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zyp4bx82z1yb2wc/calls1.dbf?dl=0

Comment: Writing a deep dive answer. I was right, but the bad news is that short of stripping the Memo field and replacing it with an inline text field there's no solution as no `dbase` library in rust that I know of handles this field type

Comment: Hi, I am the author of the dbase-rs library, i found this stackoverflow randomly.
The 'M' data type is not implemented because i do not have access to files that contains this type (and the dBase 'documentation' il almost non existant), i would have liked an issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/tmontaigu/dbase-rs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no, you will not be able to read this file with `dbase-rs` (or any current library) and you'll most likely have to rework this file to not contain a memo field.

---

## A deep dive into the DBF file format

The `InvalidFieldType` error points at a structural feature of the file that your library cannot handle - a Memo field. We're going to deep-dive into the file to figure out why that is, and whether there is anything we can do to fix it.

This is the header definition:

[image]

Of particular importance is byte 28 (offset 0000010, byte 0C), which is a bitmask indicating if the table contains a bunch of possible things, most notably:

- `0x01` if the file comes with an associated .cdx file
- `0x02` if it contains a memo
- `0x04` if the file is actually a .dbc file (a database)

At `0x03`, your file comes with both an associated .cdx file and contains a memo. As we know (ahead of time) that `dbase-rs` does not handle that, that's looking increasingly more likely.

Let's keep looking. From here on, each field is 32 bytes long.

Here are your fields:

[image]

Bytes 0-10 contain the field name, byte 11 is the type. Due to how the library you wanted to use can only parse certain fields, we only really care about byte 11.

In order of appearance by what the library can parse:

- [x] CALL_ID (integer)
- [x] CONTACT_ID (integer)
- [x] CALL_DATE (DateTime)
- [x] SUBJECT (char[])
- [ ] NOTES (memo)

The last field is the problematic one. Looking into the library itself, [this field type is not supported](https://github.com/tmontaigu/dbase-rs/blob/master/src/record/field.rs#L55) and will therefore yield an `Error`, which you are trying to `unwrap()`. This is the source of your error.

There are <strike>two</strike> three ways around it:

- The "long" way is to patch the library to handle memo fields. This sounds easy, but in practice it really isn't. As the memos are stored in another file (typically a `dbt` file in the same folder), you're going to have to make that library read both files and reference both. The point of the memo type itself is to store more than 255 bytes of data in a field. You are the only one able to evaluate whether this work is worth the effort.
- If your data is less than 255 bytes in size, you can replace that memo field with a char field, and dbfview should allow you to do this
- If your field is longer than 255 bytes and you have access to the ability to run sub-processes (i.e. `Command::run`), you can sneak-convert it using a library that **can** process Memo fields in another language. [this nodeJS library can, but read-only](https://github.com/yortus/DBFFile), for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot. As a rust learner (day 2) i am not sure yet how i will proceed to solve the issue, but your explanation really helped me understanding the problem i am facing. Thank you for your time and efforts again.

Comment: If I had a use for a proper dbase parsing library I'd help you patch it, but sadly, I don't and it's not exactly something one can do quickly :-( I'd just fix the file, tbh, unless your notes really are big.

Comment: Thank you. I will appreciate if you let me know how can i fix the file as i have almost 100 files and most of them contains the Memo field. If i know the conversion i will do it by myself.

Comment: @Shahzeb So, I may have gotten bored today, and [made a thing](https://github.com/srenauld/dbase). I'll implement `MEMO` tomorrow, I've done every other field and I have the right structure to open the `dbt` file (where the memo data is stored)

Comment: I am not able to run it. On execution "cargo test" getting errors `error: enum variants on type aliases are experimental` even after executing rustup update nightly

Comment: I'm still working on it, although that error is weird. it is stable on rust 1.37. I'm on the move atm, but I've hit another small hitch - there are two memo file formats. I've implemented the dBase 3 format, implementing the foxpro one.

Comment: Thanks for response. I upgraded to 1.37, the error is gone now. Before i had version 1.36

Comment: the good news is, I have fox pro fpt format fully working. the bad news is I don't have a dBase III/IV reference file yet and advanced DBF viewer refuses to insert memos. the search continues...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198943/discussion-between-sebastien-renauld-and-shahzeb).